# MoPub: Ad failed to load

Tags: android, ads, interstitial, mopub

I am trying to setup Interstitial Ads using Mopub on my Android Application. I have followed the tutorial at https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk/wiki/Getting-Started and get this error:

```
MoPub: Loading url: "link here"
MoPub: Ad failed to load.
```

It does not show any other errors or suggestions on how to fix this. I have been looking around but have been unable to find anything that fixes my problem. Has someone else had this problem and is there a way to fix it? Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I'm experiencing something similar U^L^

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't. I will be sure to keep you posted if I do though. It is very frustrating :/

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, though the ad was shown a couple of times first, but after that the error "Ad failed to load." showed each new time. It turned out that I had a limit for max amount of impressions set on the MoPub portal. All I had to do to resolve the problem was to remove the tick "Yes, show maximum of:" in Ad Unit settings on the portal. Hope, this can help.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I do not have any maximum impressions set.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, but this is the reason why the ADs aren't showing.

> Thank you for updating your payment information. Your account is in
>   review. You will be able to receive ads from MoPub Marketplace once
>   your account has been approved. For questions, please visit our help
>   page or contact policy@mopub.com. Tip: Monetize your inventory through
>   network mediation or with direct sales while we process your request

This was in the `MarketPlace` column of my account. In the message it explains that they have to approve your account before it can serve ADs.

The comforting thing is that my account actually gets notified when I make a request for ADs and that gives me the assurance that it is working.

I just think you have to wait till your account is approved. But their Blog says that if it persists, just contact then.

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by so many things. Honestly the best course of action is to contact support@mopub.com and they will likely have some insight on their end what the actual issue is.

In my case it was because I had turned off/paused all ad sources and orders for my ad unit. Once I had turned on at least one ad source, the failures stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to develop and test with MoPubs own test ads.
[This](https://developers.mopub.com/publishers/android/test/) link of the MoPub documentation will show you how to use test ad id's to get an ad on every request while developing.

To make things easy for you, this is a often used solution making use of the ternary operator. This says IF development THEN use the test ad id ELSE use your production ad id.

```
moPubView = (MoPubView) findViewById(R.id.adview);
moPubView.setAdUnitId(BuildConfig.DEBUG ? "b195f8dd8ded45fe847ad89ed1d016da" : "YOUR_PRODUCTION_BANNER_ID");
```

Comment: Hello, test ad is also returning nothing for me. I'm trying to integrate it in the iOS -  [MoPub][MPBannerAdManager] Banner ad view is fetching ad type: clear
[MoPub][MPBannerAdManager] No ads found for ad unit: 0ac59b0996d947309c33f59d6676399f

Comment: The ad unit should be b195f8dd8ded45fe847ad89ed1d016da for testing. You still send your production id.